# Add dict from data frame into new data frame -python & Json

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem where upon reading a JSON into a data frame, the values which i want are held within a column. These values need to be their own dataframe or expanded into the exisiting one. Is there a simple way to do this?

```
#the JSON read in as:
{"h":[
{"id":"xxx","date":"yy/mm/dd"...},
{"id":"xxy","date":"yy/mm/dd"...}
],
"count":22,"page":""}
```

As you could work out it's the values in the "h" key that i want to extract and add to a dataframe. 
However I am encountering large difficulty when doing so. The code i have is:

```
#blank dataframe
blank = pd.DataFrame()

#iterate through the dict/json values and append them to blank
for i in df.orig: 
    val = i
    blank.append(i, ignore_index=True)
```

The resulting blank dataframe contains nothing and is still a blank dataframe. Am I missing something simple or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance for you help.

PS: Iterating through the data is fine as the dataset is small and will never get large enough to be a problem for iterations

Comment: what is df.holidays and why are you iterating over it ?

Comment: It's the original dataframe where the required json data is stored in the column 'orig' (changed from holidays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below:

```
json_data = {"h":[
    {"id":"xxx","date":"yy/mm/dd"},
    {"id":"xxy","date":"yy/mm/dd"}],
    "count":22,"page":""
    }

data = json_data["h"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print df
```